# Sending email with PHP after Google Apps

Tags: php, google-apps

I am thinking about using Google Apps to handle email for my server. After changing MX records and pointing everything at Google, will my server still be able to send email through PHP? I run an install of OSCommerce which uses PHP to send order confirmation emails and I need to be sure that they will not be interrupted by this change.

Thanks!
-AJay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you should have no problems.  sendmail (or equivalent) on your server will continue to function, even if your server is no longer a mail exchanger for your domain.